# Get current version of rinetd on Raspberry Pi

Tags: packages

On my Raspberry Pi I'm using the 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS from [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/).

Now I would like to use `rinetd` on it. Unfortunately the `rinetd` package is hopelessly outdated and is for example missing IPv6 support. The latest version of `rinetd` [is 0.73](https://github.com/samhocevar/rinetd/blob/main/CHANGES.md) but the Raspberry Pi OS package contains version 0.62 from 2017.

I saw [on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rinetd) that there seems to be a 0.73 package available for the next Ubuntu.

Can I somehow force the Raspberry Pi to install that package? Since it's a very simple tool with essentially just an executable, a systemd unit file and a manpage I think there is a decent chance that it could run.

<strike>As an additional complication, when I try to list the files for the arm64 build on [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/rinetd) I get an HTTP 500. Does that mean the ARM build failed?</strike> ARM builds are not properly listed on packages, they are on [ports](http://ports.ubuntu.com/), `rinetd` is here: http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/r/rinetd/rinetd_0.73-0.1_arm64.deb

Comment: Unless the executable has been compiled for ARM its not going to work.

Comment: @DarthVader Yes, Lord Vader, the `arm64` package has been compiled for ARM.

Answer (score 0):

Build it from the source: https://github.com/samhocevar/rinetd

There are instructions there, but to carry them out you will need a few things:

```
sudo apt install gcc glibc-devel make
```

There may be more, but at a glance I don't think it has any dependencies besides libc.

It will probably be installed by default in `/usr/local/bin`. Check that is in your path: `echo $PATH`.  If not, you should add it in `/etc/profile`.

It does not come with a service file, so if you want it started at boot you will have to arrange that.

Comment: Yeah, I did that (`automake` was required as well) but that's quite a few extra steps to do on every new system where I need `rinetd`. I want a package specifically to deal with the systemd unit file, otherwise I could just put `socat` in `/etc/rc.local` or something like that.